# Full Text Index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have define full text index for a table but but when i define schedule for population there are some issues in schedule (changing "Population Type")

Please refer this image, may be it helpful for understanding.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ycRN.jpg

Kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

Recently, the opportunity arose to research how to search binary data in a database. The constraints were the document was stored in the table and it needed to work with SQL Server or Oracle. This post will, focus mostly on SQL Server.

[This article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/) shows in great detail how to setup the full-text indexing and provides great explanation as to many of the options within the syntax.

The article uses the [Adventure Works database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/). If you need the Adventure Works database.